# How does String.Equals(a,b) not produce a StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, .net

While examining the `String ==` operator, I noticed that it calls `String.Equals(string a, string b)`, meaning it's just a pass-through.

Examining the `String.Equals(string a, string b)` method, I see that it does an equality check using the `==` operator. How is this actually working and not causing a `StackOverflowException` when doing something like `"x" == "x"` or `"x" == "y"`?

**Update**: I let JetBrains know and they made it a critical priority for dotPeek. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DOTP-6789

I also added an issue on ILSpy's GitHub repo.

[image: String Equality]

Comment: The free .NET Reflector (v6) displays it "wrong" in C# (i.e. it just shows `a == b`), but correct in VB.NET: `a Is b`.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Your decompiler has a bug. [The real code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/string.cs.html#372d790ddae4cbb4) doesn't check `a == b`, it checks `(Object)a == (Object)b`, bypassing the overloaded operator.

Comment: Line 604: if ((Object)a==(Object)b) { return true; }

Comment: @DustinDavis Yeah, I had trouble managing to get the link to the right method (instead of just the right file), but updated now.

Comment: Time to submit a bug report to ILSpy

Comment: I wonder if dotPeek would produce the same buggy code as ILSpy

Comment: This is why going to the source is more reliable than decompiling

Comment: @Aravol true, but the source has only recently been released

Comment: It's pretty obfuscated code in any case though. A simple `object.ReferenceEquals(a,b)` would be much clearer..

Comment: @Voo I would argue that the current version is clearer. You don't need to know anything about `object.ReferenceEquals` with the cast version (e.g., what if `a` is `null`?), and, as long as you know what casting is, it's certainly not obfuscated.

Comment: "Your decompiler has a bug". Drops the mic.

Comment: @WChargin First you have to know that operators are statically not dynamically resolved (a misunderstanding that is common enough to warrant compiler warnings) and then what object does there (it'd be also quite reasonable to see if either side implements equatable and then call that). Referenceequals on the other side has all the hints in the name: if the two references are equal it's true else false (with what is a null reference equal? Obviously the null reference)

Comment: @Voo My guess: MS consider `(Object)a == (Object)b` and `Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` about equally readable, but it wouldn't surprise me if `Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` just has a slight chance of not getting inlined if the maximum inline depth is reached. MS does a lot of micro-optimisations, since most tight loops in user code do end up calling MS code.

Answer (score 50):

[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs) is the real code from Microsoft. Operator `==` is [implemented a](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,673)s

```
public static bool operator == (String a, String b) {
   return String.Equals(a, b);
}
```

operator `==` calls `String.Equals` [which is implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,372d790ddae4cbb4) as:

```
public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

As you see, the comparison for string equality is done using `if ((Object)a==(Object)b)` casting the string to `object` and then doing the comparison. So this will not call the overloaded operator `==` in string class.